# Cardinality of some special sets

Tags: calculus

Consider a set $\mathcal{R} = \{\{(i,j),(k,l)\}:i,j,k,l\in\{1,2,\ldots,K\},\;\mbox{and}\; i<j, k<l\}$. The cardinality of $\mathcal{R}$ is ${K\choose 2}^2$.

The set $\mathcal{R}$ can be written as union of three disjoint sets namely $\mathcal{R}_1$, $\mathcal{R}_2$, and $\mathcal{R}_3$ where

$\mathcal{R}_1 = \{\{(i,j),(k,l)\}:i=k,j=l,\; \mbox{and}\;i,j,k,l\in\{1,2,\ldots,K\},\;\mbox{and}\; i<j, k<l\}$,

$\mathcal{R}_2 = \{\{(i,j),(k,l)\}:i=k,j\neq l\text{ or }i\neq k,j=l, \; \mbox{and}\;i,j,k,l\in\{1,2,\ldots,K\},\;\mbox{and}\; i<j, k<l\}$

$\mathcal{R}_3 = \{\{(i,j),(k,l)\}:i,j\neq k,l, \; \mbox{and}\;i,j,k,l\in\{1,2,\ldots,K\},\;\mbox{and}\; i<j, k<l\}$.

I have calculated the cardinality of the set $\mathcal{R}_1$ which is equal to ${K\choose 2}$. I need help to find the carndinalities of $\mathcal{R}_2$ and $\mathcal{R}_3$.

Comment: For the set $\mathcal R$ you defined $\binom K2^2$ is incorrect; e,g,, if $K=3$, the cardinality is $6$, not $9$. But maybe you were thinking of the **ordered** pairs $((i,j),(k,l))$ instead of the **unordered** pairs $\{(i,j),(k,l)\}$?

Comment: Each such set will have a size that's quartic in $K$, so work them out for $0\le K\le 4$, then solve for coefficients.

Comment: J.G. could you please elaborate more.